# Compilation error with QueryOver and multiple SubQueries

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I'm getting the following compilation error when I'm using QueryOver with a list of sub queries:

"The type arguments for method 'xxxx' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Here is the code but not sure how I can correct it:

```
    List<QueryOver> subQueries = new List<QueryOver>();
    subQueries.Add(QueryOver.Of<Customer>().Where(...));
    subQueries.Add(QueryOver.Of<Address>().Where(...));
    subQueries.Add(QueryOver.Of<Account>().Where(...));

    var query = session.QueryOver<Customer>();

    foreach (QueryOver subQuery in subQueries)
    {
        query.WithSubquery.WhereProperty(c => c.CustomerID)
                          .In(subQuery); // this is throwing the compilation error
    }

    var result = query.Select(Projections.RowCount())
                        .FutureValue<int>()
                        .Value;
```

I need to do this programatically as I am generating the subQueries dynamically and don't know how many sub queries there will be. Do I need to use dynamic types or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this with a little refactoring. Andrew's response gave me the idea to use .Where() (instead of .WithSubquery) and then use a Conjunction for the sub queries. The refactored code looks like this:

```
    Conjunction conj = new Conjunction();
    conj.Add(Subqueries.WhereProperty<Customer>(x => x.CustomerID).In(QueryOver.Of<Customer>()...));
    conj.Add(Subqueries.WhereProperty<Customer>(x => x.CustomerID).In(QueryOver.Of<AttributeValue>()...));
    conj.Add(Subqueries.WhereProperty<Customer>(x => x.CustomerID).In(QueryOver.Of<CustomerListEntry>()...));

    ISession session = sf.OpenSession();
    using (var tran = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var query = session.QueryOver<Customer>()
                            .Where(conj)
                            .Select(Projections.RowCount())
                            .FutureValue<int>()
                            .Value;
        tran.Commit();
    }
```

I can now programatically build up and selectively apply the subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you can get around this by rewriting things slightly:

```
foreach (QueryOver subQuery in subQueries)
{
    query.Where(
        Restrictions.EqProperty(
            Projections.Property<Customer>(c => c.CustomerID),
            Projections.SubQuery(subQuery.DetachedCriteria)));
}
```

I don't know enough about your subqueries to say, but you might be able to use a `List<QueryOver<Customer>>` instead. The issue is that `.WithSubquery...In` requires a `QueryOver<U>` where your list is the non-generic base type (`QueryOver`).

Comment: Thanks Andrew - didn't quite work but it did give me an idea on how to solve! Itt didn't work because of the Restrictions.EqProperty() and the subquery return a list of values. I tried to switch it to Restrictions.In but that was expecting the actual values rather than a subquery. I ended up solving using a Conjunction().